# Using figures from xfig inside Latex

Tags: xfig

I am trying to put a simple figure into latex using the xfig package (Mac OS 10.14.6). When I use the 'Combined PS/LaTeX' I get two files, a 'pstex_t' and  'pstex' file. If I try putting the 'pstex_t' file in my Latex document (Overleaf) I get an error message. It says 'unknown graphics extension .pstex'

Is it a bad sign if when I double click the 'pstex_t' file on my desktop I get an error saying 'there is no application set to open 'test.pstex_t''?

I have been able to overcome this by using the export format 'Latex image'. However, it is very tedious to have to go back and forth between Overleaf and xfig to ensure labels are positioned exactly where I want to. This is why I still want to understand why the 'pstex_t' format doesn't work.

What could I try to do?

Answer (score 2):

Two requirements:

1. The export is to a format that is interpreted by LaTeX: Combined PS/LaTeX, Combined PDF/LaTeX, PS/PDF/LaTeX (three files), LaTeX pixture, LaTeX + pict2e macros, LaTeX + tikz macros, LaTeX + pstricks, LaTeX + eepic(emu).
2. The Text flag "TeX Flag" or, until version 3.2.7, "Special Flag" is set on the text that contains TeX/LaTeX commands.